Как построить график имея строку, а не выражение?
У меня есть строка, которую вводит пользователь и с помощью неё нужно построить график. Можно ли как-нибудь конвертировать строку в выражение?
Строка вида 'x**2+x*2+12'. Это только пример, в самом коде есть Try и Expect. пример кода:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = input()
x = np.arange(-10, 10.01, 0.01)
plt.plot(x,a)
plt.show()


Приведите примеры того, что вводит пользователь. Есть разные библиотеки, есть eval в конце-концов, но хотелось бы посмотреть на варианты формул или что там вводится. Безопаснее всё-таки заложить в код конкретные виды графиков, а пользователю давать только выбор из готовых формул и ввод их параметров.

какую строку? "парабола", "1 2 3 4 5" или "x = 2y"?

Строку с формулой зависимости. Например'2*x+x**2'

В первом приближении можно использовать eval, хотя это и очень небезопасно. Мало ли что там напишет пользователь, может он вам диск С захочет отформатировать (условно говоря).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = input() # x**2+x*2+12
x = np.arange(-10, 10.01, 0.01)
y = eval(a)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()


